# using mysql join to show not match value

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, join

I have a query to join 3 tables.

```
$this->db->select("a.user_id as id, a.plate_number as plate_number, a.current_lat as lat, a.current_lon as lon, a.created_on as created_on, a.updated_on as updated_on, a.available as available, a.location_id as location_id, b.user_name as name, b.user_email as email, b.user_phone as phone, c.name as location_name");
        $this->db->from('user_driver as a');
        $this->db->join('user as b', 'a.user_id = b.user_id');
        $this->db->join('vendor_location as c', 'a.location_id = c.location_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $data['driver'] = $query->result_array();
```

`user_driver` table structure:
[image: user_driver]

`vendor_location` table structure:
[image: vendor_location]

The result :
[image: result]

I want to show the rest of `user_driver` table even though there are not matching value to `vendor_location` table. The `LocationName` field could be filled `NULL` instead of not showing anything at all.

I tried `left outer` and `full outer` but it's not working. It left me with the only one row showing.

Comment: Which is the foreign key in the vendor_location table?

Comment: Approach this way: `...user_driver INNER JOIN user ON .... LEFT JOIN vendor_location ON. ..`

Comment: `location_id` @AT-2016

Comment: please replace teh screenshots with real data (copy pastable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have u tried like this

```
$this->db->join('user as b', 'a.user_id = b.user_id', 'LEFT');
    $this->db->join('vendor_location as c', 'a.location_id = c.location_id', 'LEFT');
```

Comment: thank you, I should add `left` on both join queries :)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to show the rest of user_driver table even though there are not matching value to vendor_location table.

For this, you should use [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html). It allows you to fetch rows from table in left side even when there is no match in right table.

```
$this->db->select("a.user_id as id, a.plate_number as plate_number, a.current_lat as lat, a.current_lon as lon, a.created_on as created_on, a.updated_on as updated_on, a.available as available, a.location_id as location_id, b.user_name as name, b.user_email as email, b.user_phone as phone, c.name as location_name");
$this->db->from('user_driver as a');
$this->db->join('user as b', 'a.user_id = b.user_id');
$this->db->join('vendor_location as c', 'a.location_id = c.location_id', 'left');//modify this line
$query = $this->db->get();
$data['driver'] = $query->result_array();
```

Comment: i just have to add `left` on both `join` queries. thanks btw :)